# Executing JavaScript on multi-row table rendering

Tags: javascript, html, jsf, primefaces

I'm using a custom Primefaces-based framework to display a datatable, and it looks like that:

```
<xy:dataTable id="tableId" value="#{lazyTableBean.dates}" var="date">
    <xy:column id="nameColumnId">
        <xy:outputText id="nameOutputId" value="date.name"/>
    </xy:column>

    <xy:column id="actionColumnId">
        <xy:actionButton id="actionButtonId" label="Button"
            action="#{someBean.someAction(date.id)}"/>                          
    </xy:column>
</xy:dataTable>
```

Now I want to set the tooltip of the button. Since the actionButton component of that framework doesn't have the title attribute, I'm using JavaScript to alter it:

```
var rows = // getting the table content row components here

// iterating through table rows and setting the button tooltip to the name of the corresponding date
for (const row of rows) {
    var myTooltip = row.children.item(0).textContent;
    row.children.item(1).firstChild.setAttribute("title", myTooltip);
}
```

This basically works as it should when I import the JS script at the end of the file.
However, there are several AJAX events (e.g. when sorting or filtering the table, or when using pagination...) that reprint the table content. Since the JS script isn't triggered again, the tooltips aren't set in that case.

Now I've planned to simply import the script at some appropriate place (e.g. inside the component that gets rerendered) so that it's executed whenever the button is rendered. However, I haven't found quite the right place to make it work. When I'm putting it inside the column:

```
<xy:dataTable id="tableId" value="#{lazyTableBean.dates}" var="date">
    <xy:column id="nameColumnId">
        <xy:outputText id="nameColumnId" value="date.name"/>
    </xy:column>

    <xy:column id="actionColumnId">
        <xy:actionButton id="actionColumnId" label="Button"
            action="#{someBean.someAction(date.id)}"/> 
        <h:outputScript library="js" name="addTooltipToTableButtons.js" />                
    </xy:column>
</xy:dataTable>
```

This results in only the first row to correctly set their tooltip, all other rows keep their generic one. But on AJAX events, the correct behavior takes place, all rows set their tooltip correctly. The same behavior takes place if the script is also imported at the end. I guess this has to do with the table format of dynamically printing a number of rows with the same column components, but this is just guessing.

Putting it inside the table (directly before `</xy:dataTable>`) results in no script execution at all.

I'm totally new to JavaScript and we're just using this approach until our custom framework supports setting arbitrary attributes. I hope you have an idea (or an explanation why it won't work like that) - thanks in advance!

Greetings

Comment: Move the `outputScript` outside of the table it does not belong there.  And you can do it with some simple Jquery to find all buttons and add the Title attribute.

Comment: Alright, but will the JQuery version magically execute again after Ajax events? No experience with JQuery yet.

Comment: Just add `oncomplete="yourJs()"` to your AJAX events to call this custom JS after any AJAX event is done.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone's interested in my solution, I used a MutationObserver to handle the events, *in addition* to the "normal" JS at page load.

The whole JS file looked like that:

```
var table = ...; // get table by normal means

for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
    var tooltip = row.cells[0].textContent;
    row.cells[1].firstChild.setAttribute(tooltip);
}

var observer = new MutationObserver(function( mutations ) {
  mutations.forEach(function( mutation ) {
    var newNodes = mutation.addedNodes;
    if( newNodes !== null ) {
        var $nodes = $( newNodes );
        $nodes.each(function() {
            var tooltip = this.cells[0].textContent;
            this.cells[1].firstChild.setAttribute(tooltip);
        });
    }
  });    
});

var config = { 
    attributes: true, 
    childList: true, 
    characterData: true 
};
 
observer.observe(table.children.item(1), config);
```